# Obtener ruta absoluta de un archivo txt

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Necesito obtener la ruta absoluta en Android de un archivo .txt después de un file chooser

**Tengo este Código:**

```
private String myPath;
Uri datos;  
private static final int COD_SELECCIONA_TXTART = 10;  

public void elegirArchivo(View vista){
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("text/*");
startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Elige una aplicación"),COD_SELECCIONA_TXTART);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode){
        case COD_SELECCIONA_TXTART:
            Uri datos = data.getData();
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(datos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
```

Necesito mostrar la ruta absoluta en el Toast pero me sale algo como:

> content://com.mobisystems.fileman.RemoteFiles/ZmlsZTov....

Pero necesito obtenerlo algo así:

> /storage/emulated/carpeta/carpeta/carpeta/nombre_archivo.txt

**¿Cómo lo hago?**

Comment: Hace falta más información, nombre_archivo.txt es un objeto de tipo FIle que tienes creado?

Comment: @AngelGonzalezPena El nombre_archivo.txt es un ejemplo del archivo de texto que el usuario seleccione, es decir, necesito obtener la ruta absoluta de ese archivo que el usuario seleccionó

Comment: has intentado con: `DocumentFile` algo como: `String filePath = null;
if (uri != null) {DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, uri);if (documentFile != null && documentFile.exists()) {filePath = documentFile.getUri().getPath();}} return filePath;`

Answer (score -1):

Hola puede probar si funciona así, dentro del OnActivityResult

```
  if (requestCode == COD_SELECCIONA_TXTART && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        datos = data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(this, datos+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Hola Ricardo, esto es lo que ha tratado, revisa el código de la pregunta, saludos.

Comment: esto no es y no explica como lo soluciona...

Answer (score -1):

Ami me funciono esto a la perfección espero que os sirva:

```
package es.resisg.openvideo;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int SELECCIONAR_ARCHIVO_REQUEST_CODE = 10;
    TextView txtViewPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtViewPath =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewPath);
    }
    public void search(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECCIONAR_ARCHIVO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SELECCIONAR_ARCHIVO_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String filePath = getFileNameFromUri(uri);
                txtViewPath.setText(filePath);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getFileNameFromUri(Uri uri) {
        //creamos la variable filePath
        String filePath = null;

        /*Dentro de 'docId' obtenemos el ID del del URI que es de tipo("android:ruta/del/archivo.xyz")
        y le hacemos un split={"android","ruta/del/archivo.xyz"}*/
        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        final String[] split = docId.split(":");

        /*Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() con esto obtenemos '/storage/emulated/0'
        split[1]='ruta/del/archivo.xyz'
        en conjunto es '/storage/emulated/0/ruta/del/archivo.xyz' para obtener la ruta completa del
        archivo que estemos buscando*/
        filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1];

        return filePath;

    }

    public void execute(View view){
        //Obtenemos el texto de la parte gráfica de la aplicacion
        String filePath = txtViewPath.getText().toString();
        if(filePath.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Tienes que Seleccionar un archivo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            // Crea un Intent con la acción ACTION_VIEW y la URI del archivo
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");

            // Inicia la actividad con el Intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: esto no es y no explica como lo soluciona...